# Why does integrating Rails with Dropbox Chooser returns SSL connect error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox, carrierwave

I'm adding [Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser) to a Rails 3.2 app.

The basic premise is that the User selects files from Dropbox, and a listener submits the resulting direct URLs to Carrierwave on successful selection.

However the model is returning the following error on create

```
"could not download file: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed"
```

If I copy and paste the URL from the logs into a browser, the file is accessible.

Why is this error being generated, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I assume you're getting a direct link from the Chooser, not a preview link, right? (So the domain in question is dl.dropboxusercontent.com?) Could you share some code? What does the code look like that accesses the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to the result of out of date SSL certificates on my development machine.

I use RVM, and this solved the problem

```
$ rvm -v
$ rvm get head
$ rvm -v
# rvm 1.19.1 (master)
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
# Certificates for...
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
# Updating certificates...
```

Thanks to this post http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add trusted-certs.crt file in rails /vendor dir.
Content of file can be found here.....https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-ruby/master/lib/trusted-certs.crt

Copy and paste it to vendor/trusted-certs.crt and you are ready to go.